# Loss is very big from the beginning, and almost not decreasing in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to perform linear regression in tensorflow. I don't understand why from the beginning my loss is so big. What is more, the decrease in loss is very small during training.
Could you please tell me if there are any mistakes in my code that may cause this problem?
If it is important, I used Kaggle dataset - "House price prediction" - which can be found at kaggle at /shree1992/housedata.

I paste my code below:

```
import sys

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Loading and inspecting the data:

data = pd.read_csv('dataset/data.csv')
print(data.head(1))
data = data.drop('street', 1)
data = data.drop('statezip', 1)

print(data.head(1))
# Encoding categorical data - street, city, statezip, country:
data = pd.get_dummies(data, columns=["city", "country"])

data = data.values
X = np.array(data[:, 2:], dtype=np.float)
Y = np.array(data[:, 1], dtype=np.float)
print(X.shape)
# it had 4600 observations, 4659 features before dropping two columns - (4600, 57)
#after dropping 'street' and 'statezip' - (4600, 57)



# Splitting the data into training and test sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3)
N, D = X_train.shape

# Scaling the data
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

# Creating a model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(D,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(0.001, 0.9), loss='mse')
# model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')


# learning rate scheduler
def schedule(epoch, lr):
    if epoch >= 50:
        return 0.0001
    return 0.001


scheduler = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(schedule)


# Train the model
r = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=200, callbacks=[scheduler])
```

Below you can find a fragment of results of running this code:

```
Epoch 38/200
101/101 [==============================] - 0s 464us/step - loss: 270232453120.0000
Epoch 39/200
101/101 [==============================] - 0s 464us/step - loss: 270549336064.0000
Epoch 40/200
101/101 [==============================] - 0s 464us/step - loss: 270402207744.0000
Epoch 41/200
101/101 [==============================] - 0s 619us/step - loss: 270913732608.0000
Epoch 42/200
101/101 [==============================] - 0s 464us/step - loss: 271168536576.0000
Epoch 43/200
101/101 [==============================] - 0s 464us/step - loss: 270916206592.0000
Epoch 44/200
101/101 [==============================] - 0s 464us/step - loss: 272359129088.0000
Epoch 45/200
101/101 [==============================] - 0s 619us/step - loss: 271552167936.0000
Epoch 46/200
101/101 [==============================] - 0s 464us/step - loss: 272676618240.0000
Epoch 47/200
101/101 [==============================] - 0s 619us/step - loss: 272397254656.0000
Epoch 48/200
101/101 [==============================] - 0s 464us/step - loss: 270996291584.0000
Epoch 49/200
101/101 [==============================] - 0s 619us/step - loss: 271571435520.0000
Epoch 50/200
101/101 [==============================] - 0s 464us/step - loss: 272347545600.0000
Epoch 51/200
101/101 [==============================] - 0s 619us/step - loss: 269679640576.0000
```

Comment: In last few days I tried to decrease the number of features, but loss is still very big. Do you have any ideas what could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: try fitting your model  without any callbacks and then say the result